# How to Fetch Json Array in Android kotlin

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin, retrofit

["", "PAKISTAN", "National", "Identity", "Card", "ISLAMIC", "REPUBLIC", "OF", "PAKISTAN", "Name", "Saad", "Hanif", "Qureshi", "3-3-20", "Father", "Name", "Muhammad", "Hanif", "Qureshi", "Gender", "Country", "of", "Stay", "M", "Saudi", "Arabia", "Identity", "Number", "Date", "of", "Birth", "42301-6685580-7", "13.06.1986", "38902", "Date", "of", "Issue", "Date", "of", "Expiry", "06.01.2021", "06.01.2031", "Holder's", "Signature"]

Comment: Need to be more specific with your question. This site isn't for requesting tutorials.

Comment: i am getting null list arraylist